# MultipleObjectsReturned at /api/rentals/gallery/1/

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.9

I need to show multiple images in detail view of gallery api but i am getting an error stating

**MultipleObjectsReturned at /api/rentals/gallery/1/**

**get() returned more than one Gallery -- it returned 2!**

**views.py**

```
class GalleryListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    # queryset = Rental.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GalleryListSerializer
    pagination_class = RentalPageNumberPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset_list = Gallery.objects.all()
        return queryset_list

class GalleryDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Gallery.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GalleryDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'rental_id'
```

**serializers.py**

```
class GalleryListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery

class GalleryDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # image = SerializerMethodField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ('id', 'image', 'rental_id')
```

Comment: As the error says, you have two Gallery objects with rental_id=1.

Comment: Could you please to add the models as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes)

> `lookup_field` - The model field that should be used to for performing object lookup of individual model instances. Defaults to `'pk'`.

Since you have used `rental_id` and you are using the url `/api/rentals/gallery/1/` here `1` is the `rental_id` and not the `pk` of the Gallery. And, it might be that there are two gallery objects related to `rental_id=1` and that's why you are getting those in the result.